# Order Bookshelf.js fetch by related column value

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm using Bookshelf.js/Knex.js, fetching a model (call it user) with a related child model (call it company).
**Can I order by a field on the child model - `company.name`?**

Also, if that's possible, can I multi sort, say `company.name` descending then `lastName` ascending

Here's my current code, which only works on root model fields.  `qb.orderBy('company.name', 'desc')` doesn't work.

```
users.query(function(qb) {
  qb.orderBy('lastName', 'asc');
})
.fetch({withRelated: ['company']})
.then(success, error);
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
users
.fetch({withRelated: [
     {
         'company': function(qb) {
             qb.orderBy("name");
         }
     }
]})
.then(success, error);
```

I got the idea from https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/361

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this without the need of a function:

```
users.query(function(qb) {
  qb.query('orderBy', 'lastName', 'asc');
})
.fetch({withRelated: ['company']})
.then(success, error);
```

Found here: [Sort Bookshelf.js results with .orderBy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068144/sort-bookshelf-js-results-with-orderby)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by doing this:

```
let postHits =
    await posts
        .query(qb => qb
            .innerJoin('post_actor_rel', function () {
                this.on('post.id', '=', 'post_actor_rel.post_id');
            })
            .innerJoin('actor', function () {
                this.on('post_actor_rel.actor_id', '=', 'actor.id');
            })
            .orderByRaw('actor.name ASC')
            .groupBy('id')
        )
        .fetchPage({
            withRelated: ['roles', 'themes', 'activity_types', 'subjects', 'educational_stages', 'images', 'documents', 'actors'],
            limit,
            offset
        },
    );
```

I modify the query by inner joining with the desired tables and after sorting (using orderByRaw since I will need to add some more sorting that I think is not possible with orderBy) I group by the *post's* id to get rid of the duplicate rows. The only problem is that it's not defined which *actor* name (of several possible) is used for the sorting.