# Bookshelf.js orderBy related column

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Someone asked this before ([Order Bookshelf.js fetch by related column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568153/order-bookshelf-js-fetch-by-related-column-value)) but the answers didn't work out for me.

Lets say I have the following models

```
var FirstModel = DB.Model.extend{
    tableName: 'first',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    createdAt: 'created_at'
}

var SecondModel = DB.Model.extend{
    tableName: 'second',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    firstModel: function(){
        return this.belongsTo(FirstModel,'firstModel_id')
    }
}
```

Inside my query I specify to order the results by `created_at`

```
SecondModel.forge().fetchAll({
    withRelated: [{
        'firstModel': function(qb){
            qb.orderBy('created_at','asc');
        }
    }]
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result.toJSON());
});
```

Unfortunately the resulting collection isn't sorted according to my query.

Is it possible to do such a thing ?